# Scriptella : command not found

Tags: unix, scriptella

After installing scriptella, I get

```
command scriptella not found.
```

So I added the  `<SCRIPTELLA_DIR>/bin` to `PATH` by appending it in `~/.zshrc` file to make it permanently and verify that `scriptella` is added to the path.

But I still get this error

```
$ echo $PATH 
/var/lib/scriptella/bin:/home/tah/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Comment: This is the result of `echo $PATH` /var/lib/scriptella/bin:/home/tah/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

Comment: Are you sure this program is located there? try `find / -name scriptella  -type f`

Comment: `/var` is an odd place to put binaries compared to `/usr/local`, but what happens when you run `/var/lib/scriptella/bin/scriptella` directly? Is that command actually executable? Can you please show `ls -lR /var/lib/scriptella/`?